# Creating Tempory column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database(MySQL) there is a field that holds birthday. When I retrieving records I want to print there age doing like this `age = (YEAR(CUERRENT_DATE) - YEAR(birthday))`. But in my database there is no column called age. So I just want to do, create temporary column and hold the age, and when I retrieving records I can print age also. Is there a way to do this? How can I write the query? I am new to SQL. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a temporary column, simply select:

```
SELECT YEAR(CUERRENT_DATE) - YEAR(birthday) AS age, otherColumns FROM xyz WHERE ...
```

As you see, I used AS for renaming the expression to your "temporary column". It will then appear in your result set.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the age directly in SELECT, and return it like if it was a column:

```
SELECT *, YEAR(CUERRENT_DATE) - YEAR(birthday) as age
FROM table
...
```

This is like a temporary column.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you do not need to store age - you retrieve the birth date from SQL and calculate the age in code and print. Aslo you can use DB inbuilt functions to get the current date  - if you want to do that in SQL.

If you are using MySQL.

```
SELECT (YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birth)) AS age FROM TABLE_NAME;
```